# non-fixed repeatInterval in UILocalNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

I've been cracking my head on this one for weeks now.

What happens if I set the `repeatInterval` property of a `UILocalNotification` to be a non-fixed interval? (by non-fixed I mean units such as `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit` and `NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit`).

So say I have `UILocalNotification` with its `fireDate` set to the Wednesday in the current week, and I set the `repeatInterval` to be `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit`. Will it repeat every Wednesday?

Is the same true for `NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit`? So if I have a notification with the `fireDate` set to be the 4th Wednesday of the month, and I set the `repeatInterval` to be `NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit`, will it repeat every 4th Wednesday of every month?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That sounds reasonable.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I just tried the NSWeekdayCalendarUnit repeatInteval and it doesn't work like it should, instead of repeating the same day of the following week, it got repeated on Friday of the same week. I'll have to wait a month before being able to test the other one (or I could just change my iPod's date).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, for the benefit of everyone, here's what I found:

- Setting the repeat interval to `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit` doesn't work how I expected, instead, I suppose it looks for every occurrence of that weekday inside a week, and because there is only one, it then schedules the notification for the end of that week (the default is Saturday)
- In a similar way, setting it to `NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit` creates a similar behavior, in that, seeing that there is no more occurrences of X ordinal of X day, it resorts to scheduling to the las ordinal for that weekday in a month.

Comment: I think I should file a feature request for this behavior